# Vectorize grouped summation

Tags: python, numpy

I have an algorithm with plain Python loops which I would like to optimize
for speed.

Starting from an array indicating bin indices, I want summed up values for those bins.

More detailed: I start from an index array pointing to a vector of values and values for the same index should be summed up. The plain and slow Python version is like:

```
import numpy

ix     = numpy.array([0 , 1 , 1 , 4 ])
values = numpy.array([10, 20, 30, 40])

# this models bin assignment:
# 10 belongs to bin 0
# 20 and 30 belong  to bin 1
# 40 belongs to bin 4

summed = numpy.zeros_like(values)

for i in ix:
    summed[i] += values[ix[i]]

print summed

[10, 50, 0, 0, 40]
```

This is quite slow and I ask if anybody can give me a hint how to
vectorize this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy.bincount()`:

```
>>> numpy.bincount(ix, values)
array([ 10.,  50.,   0.,   0.,  40.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a hack but this gives the same result

```
indicator = np.arange(5)[None, ...] == ix[..., None]
summed = np.sum(values[..., None] * indicator, axis=0)
```

Comment: This approach has quadratic runtime and memory usage.

Comment: Yeah it's not great...!